# How to ignore wp_link_pages function?

Tags: wp-link-pages

I've bought a wordpress theme. I want to ignore all wp_link_pages functions from theme files. I will write my custom codes.

Is there any way to do it with functions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_link_pages`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/) has two filters you can use:

- The [`wp_link_pages_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_link_pages_args/) filter is passed the `$args` for `wp_link_pages` so you could set `echo` to false.
- The [`wp_link_pages`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_link_pages/) filter is passed the output so you could set the output to nil. Something like this should work:

```
/**
 * Filter the HTML output of page links for paginated posts.
 *
 * @param  string $output HTML output of paginated posts' page links.
 * @param  array  $args   An array of arguments.
 * @return string $output HTML output of paginated posts' page links.
 **/
add_filter('wp_link_pages', 'wpse_218590_hide_wp_link_pages', 10, 2);
function wpse_218590_hide_wp_link_pages( $output, $args )
{
    return '';
}
```

*This isn't tested and I only had a quick look at the filters so it may not be 100% correct but it should give you an idea of what to do*

Comment: Thanks CAI. It removed all wp_link_pages. But how can I write my custom wp_link_pages code?

Comment: Thats doable.. but you should probably ask a new question for that as it's way out of the scope of this question.

Comment: added wp_link_pages() function to custom_wp_link_pages() now, it works..

Comment: Glad you got it working :)